# A way to selectively deliver UILocalNotifications to iPhone vs Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit

I'm trying to create a feature where certain UILocalNotifications trigger a sound despite the fact that they are displayed in an Apple Watch, or if that's not possible, are not routed at all to the Apple Watch and just to an iPhone where they can play a sound. Having the watch produce a sound is not ideal compared to the iPhone since I need it to overlay any music the user is playing on headphones.

Obviously the user can disable notifications on the Apple Watch for the app, but there are cases where it is useful to receive notifications on the Apple Watch and that is an all-or-nothing solution.

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html) states:

> When one of your app’s local or remote notifications arrives on the user’s iPhone, iOS decides whether to display that notification on the iPhone or on the Apple Watch.

Is there any information on how iOS decides where to display a notification? Is there any programmatic way to disable notification forwarding to Apple Watch?

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively disable notification in apple watch: http://www.imore.com/how-turn-alerts-apps-apple-watch

See the answer in below link for app’s local or remote notifications guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33581623/2401116

Comment: Thanks, I was looking more for a programmatic way of doing this from app code, e.g. some property on UILocalNotification or some registration setting for notifications.